# woocommerce hook add to cart button and save custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I first followed the guideline to override the single product page by creating a woocommerce folder in my theme root, then created a single.product.php, and inside this file, I added the following:

```
<div class="product-content flex">
    <figure class="thumbnail">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </figure>
    <main id="product-content">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p>R <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); ?></p>
        <div class="description">
            <?php the_content();  ?>
        </div>
        <div class="flex size">
            <span>Product size</span>
            <select name="product_size" id="product_size">
                <option value="small">Small</option>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="flex quantity">
            <span>Quantity</span>
            <input type="number" name="quanitity" id="product_quantity">
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

First: how can I now hook up the add to cart button?
Lastly, after hooking the add to cart, how can I save the size and quantity?

Comment: @MominIqbal The reference you send sounds a bit vague compared to my question.
mind giving better guidance so I can achieve the result of my question?

Comment: you need to take reference of the existing single-product.php in a woocommerce plugin

Comment: if you just need to save size simply can use default woocommerce Variable Products. set as variables as you need and it shows in single product page.(if not you should look for changes in file `woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for add to cart button

```
<a href="<?php
          $add_to_cart = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="'.get_the_ID().'"]');
          echo $add_to_cart;
?>" class="more">Buy now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use default woocommerce variable product - [Variable Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/)?

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I set the product data to a variable product, created the attribute and added variation.
When I visit the page I now see the following: THIS PRODUCT IS CURRENTLY OUT OF STOCK AND UNAVAILABLE..

Comment: In this case check the inventory of all variation, and make sure all variation has a price.